# ASP.NET if root URL contains query string, pass it to default.aspx on redirect

Tags: asp.net, query-string

Is there any way that I can preserve a query string and pass it to the default.aspx;
For example:

> http://www.example.com/?test=123

becomes

> http://www.example.com/Default.aspx?test=123

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also do it in javascript like this: `window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com/' + location.search);` Try: http://jsfiddle.net/yq5gj3rm/show/?test=123

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. You could use `Request.QueryString["test"]` to get the value from query string and pass it to the other page using

```
if(Request.QueryString["test"] != null)
{
      Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx?test=" + Request.QueryString["test"].ToString())
}
```

Do this in Session_Start method of Global.asax.cs

Or if you want to pass the entire query string instead of one value just use `Request.QueryString.ToString()`

Comment: you can also use `Request.Url.Query` to get the raw query string as a string.  I would also recommend using HttpUtility because you wont have to worry about things like parsing and encoding.  `Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx?test=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode (Request.QueryString["test"]))`